# coalesce doesn't work when grouping is used

Tags: coldfusion, group-by, sum, coalesce

I have an easy question. I'm trying to use `coalesce` in combination with a `group by` clause. I want to get 0 values when the variable is null. Here is my sql server code:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0)) AS NETTOTAL,DATEPART(MM,RECORD_DATE) MONTH 
FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_EMPLOYEE_ID=#attributes.record_emp_id# 
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM,RECORD_DATE) ORDER BY MONTH
```

.. and my output:

```
<tr height="20">
    <td>Orders</td>
    <cfoutput query="get_orders"><td style="text-align:center;">#tlformat(nettotal,2)# - #month#</td></cfoutput>
</tr>
```

This code is just for the orders. There is also the sales row. Anyway here is the screenshot to make it more clear:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIAmr.png

To make it more clear I added the number of the month. As you can see the order is broken since there are no zero values for the other months...

P.S.Thank you all for the help! i really appreciate it!

Comment: What do you get if you run that on SQL-server?

Comment: @Schiavini there is a screenshot, have a look at it

Comment: This is from coldfusion, not from the SQL Server management studio

Comment: @Schiavini ok no problem, edited, but what is `SELECT SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0)) AS NETTOTAL` etc then?

Comment: Just a minor point, you should probably wrap #attributes.record_emp_id# in a queryparam so <cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.record_emp_id#"> - just a pet hate of mine seeing inputs outside of parameters!

Comment: @Simonatmso.net ok no prob :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not at fault.  You are trying to select from ORDERS based on each employee_id.  You are then looping over it.

If a given month has no orders, then there will be no row for it within the result set.

Even if there were only orders for the last 4 months, they would get pushed to the first 4 as you are not checking that the month you are currently outputting matches the column header.

For a bit of metacode, I would go down this route

1 - create an array as follows

```
arrMonths= [
    {orders=0,sales=0},
    {orders=0,sales=0}....
]
```

This will give you a stc you can iterate over later.

2 - I would then loop over each query

```
<cfoutput query="get_orders">
    <cfset arrMonths[month].orders = nettotal>
</cfoutput>
```

3 - I would then iterate over the array

```
<tr height="20">
    <td>Orders</td>
    <cfoutput from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrMonths)#" index="thisMonth">
        <td style="text-align:center;">#tlformat(arrMonths[thisMonth].orders,2)# - #thisMonth#</td>
    </cfoutput>
</tr>
```

This way, every month will ALWAYS have a value even if it's 0.  You can also ditch the coalesce as the simple fact that rows with no orders have no records means they default to 0 so your query may become

```
SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL)) AS NETTOTAL,
    DATEPART(MM,RECORD_DATE) MONTH 
FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ORDER_EMPLOYEE_ID=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.record_emp_id#">
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM,RECORD_DATE)
```

MONTH is now not necessary as it's just inserting into the array which deals with ordering

Comment: Thank you simon, i knew it already :) so what do u suggest? how do i write it then, so that there would be zero values if null?

Comment: There updated with a more full solution, that's the kind of method I'd use anyway so hope it's of help.  Your table data is taken from a Coldfusion array which has 0 as default for each table cell.  You then fill out any for which there are database records in the query as you go.

Comment: It scales quite well also, especially if you can get the data collection queries down into a single efficient query instead of 1 for each field

Answer (score 0):

TRy ISNULL() Instead of COALESCE .
COALESCE is used for multiple argumentsif multiple arguments are not needed you could use ISNULL

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert the order of the functions Sum and Coalesce.
IsNull might be more readable as well:

```
SELECT   IsNull(SUM(NETTOTAL), 0) AS NETTOTAL,
         DATEPART(MM, RECORD_DATE) MONTH 
FROM     ORDERS
WHERE    ORDER_EMPLOYEE_ID = #attributes.record_emp_id# 
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, RECORD_DATE)
ORDER BY MONTH
```

If there are no elements of NETTOTAL, Coalesce from your code would not be called. So a Sum of no rows will be null.